# Manager isn't accessible via Police instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

Error is occurred in if user.objects.filter(login_id=login_obj).exists(): how to solve this error

This is my police_app/views.py

```
def police_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        login_obj = Login()
        login_obj.username = request.POST.get('uname')
        login_obj.password = request.POST.get('pwd')
        login_obj.save()
        if Login.objects.filter(username=request.POST.get('uname')).exists():
            user = Police()
            user.station_name = request.POST.get('name')
            user.email = request.POST.get('email')
            user.mobile = request.POST.get('mob')
            user.district = request.POST.get('district')
            user.state = request.POST.get('state')
            user.login_id = login_obj
            user.save()
            if user.objects.filter(login_id=login_obj).exists():
                return render(request, "login.html")
        return render(request, "police_app/police_register.html", context={'error': 'Registration failed'})
    return render(request, "police_app/police_register.html")
```

Comment: You want to use `Police` not `user`

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

> Manager isn't accessible via Police instances

This already explains the cause of the error. You tried to call the model manager via instance, which is not valid. Instead, you should access the manager via model class.

## Solution

Change

```py
if user.objects.filter(login_id=login_obj).exists():
    ...
```

to

```py
if Police.objects.filter(login_id=login_obj).exists():
    ...
```